# Spring JPA Join Efficiency - Create a query for each iteration

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple 2 JPA entities which I have a Join Between them:

Primary entity **Country**:

```
public class Country implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "MCC")
  private String mcc;

  ......

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "mcc", referencedColumnName = "mcc")
  private List<CountryInfo> countryInfo;
```

Joint entity **CountryInfo**:

```
public class CountryInfo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "mcc")
  private String mcc;

  @Column(name = "continent")
  private String continent;
```

When I've turned on my configuration to dump the queries being executed, I've noticed that for each **Country** found, another call is done on the **CountryInfo** entity with the mcc specified..

This is obviously slow since rather than creating 1 call with a JOIN, it is executing N + 1 queries (where N = count of **Country**).

I've already seen this tutorial https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jpa-correctly-to-avoid-complaints-of-a-slow-application/ and changed accordingly but it is still calling N + 1 queries..

Is there a way to overcome this?

---

**EDIT**

In order to get the data I have a **Repository**:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<E212MCC, Long>, 
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<E212MCC> {
}
```

And then call with some specifications:

```
List<E212MCC> countries = this.countryRepository.findAll(specifications);
```

Comment: How are you selecting your Country instance, and have you tried using a fetch join in the query over the countryInfo relationship?

Comment: @Chris Updated my question to show how data is being loaded.. No I haven't tried using Fetch Join.. I'll do some research on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Specifications` you could try with specification that performs fetch join operation (I am assuming that you are using JPA meta model):

```
private Specification<Country> joinContryInfo() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        root.fetch(Country_.countryInfo);
        // here you can fetch more entities if you need...
        return null;
    };
}
```

And then, just add it to your specification object:

```
Specifications.where(joinCountryInfo())
```

If you are not using meta model then just replace `Country_.countryInfo` with `"countryInfo"` string.

If you are using `CountryInfo` fields for searching, you can omit `joinContryInfo()` specification and prepare join and search query in one specification:

```
private Specification<Country> continentEqual(String param) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<Country,CountryInfo> join = (Join) root.fetch(Country_.countryInfo);
        return cb.equal(join.get(CountryInfo_.continent), addWildCards(param));;
    };
}
```